# Show dialog Google-Apps-Script for a shared link

Tags: google-apps-script

The code below works on a document I am the owner of. When I share a link to it (with edit privileges), it does not respond for the editor. Any idea what is the cause of it?

```
function onEdit(event) {
showDialog();  
} // I also have this function listed under triggers for 'On edit' events

function showDialog() { 
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('revRequestUI')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(700)
      .setHeight(320);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(ui, ' ');
}
```

Comment: An installed edit trigger only runs under the account of the person that installed it. Perhaps use a menu option instead. Also, it is very bad practice to double-schedule a trigger - using the name `onEdit` creates a simple (no authorized service usage) trigger.

Comment: @tehhowch Can you elaborate on menu option idea? Custom menus do not work under shared link either. Regarding double-scheduling, I see your point but I found it is the only way parts of my script would work. Thanks